# Process: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile, helper

I am creating 1 music player app and I get this error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.appnghenhac, PID: 11560
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:389)
        at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:581)
        at com.example.appnghenhac.Fragment.Fragment_Playlist$2.onResponse(Fragment_Playlist.java:69)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:70)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear...

Comment: share the code. i think you make small mistake.

Answer (score 1):

onResponse is **Null** present.

```
if (your_response != null && !your_response.isEmpty()) {
  // doSomething
}else{
   // Empty response or null ( this line stop app crash)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The list where you are trying to call .size() method is null.
Put a null check before calling .size() method on the object. Also figure out why that object is null.

```
if (list != null) {
 println(list.size())
}

//kotlin
list?.size()
```